# How to prove the following inequality problem?

Tags: inequality

Define $$S=\sum _{r=1}^n a_r$$

> How to prove the following inequality:
> $$\prod _{r=1}^n (1+a_r)\leq \sum _{r=0}^n \frac{S^r}{r!}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation for how to properly render math here, instead of giving a link to the problem, which is *strongly depreceated*.

Comment: Are you sure this is true and there is no condition on $a_r$ ?

Comment: There should be some sort of condition. If we take $a_1 = a_2 = \ldots = a_n = 0$, then S = 0 and we get $1 \le 0$ which is absurd.

Comment: @Oussema Your argument requires to  reject $0^0 / 0! = 1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? : The answer by @coffeemath at: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/485552/317854